# Rails Sunspot/Solr Index Out of Sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm using the `sunspot-rails` gem for searching and filtering but am running into issues where Solr queries are not returning the correct results. For example, say I want to retrieve all the records of a model with `state == Processing`, and I do the following Sunspot search:

```
MyModel.search do
    # pagination and ordering stuff
    ...
    with('state', 'Processing')
    ...
end
```

Most of the time, this returns the correct results. Sometimes (and so far only on production, I can't duplicate the issue locally) the query will return records with `state == In Review`. If I do a regular ActiveRecord `MyModel.where(state: 'Processing')` I always get the correct results.

I thought it might have to do with my solrconfig.yml file but changing those params haven't seemed to change anything. Relevant portion of that file:

```
<autoCommit>
   <maxTime>15000</maxTime>
   <maxDocs>1000</maxDocs>
   <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
 </autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
   <maxTime>5000</maxTime>
 </autoSoftCommit>
```

Does anyone have any pointers for why changes in my db aren't reflected in the Solr index, or how I can debug/log what's going on? This is on a small internal app with maybe 100 users or so. I shouldn't have to reindex Solr daily to keep the results up to date.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the time difference between the query being made and the document being shown? Does a document go from Processing (i.e. is the status in Solr processing) to In review? Can that change happen in the second or two that an update may take?

Comment: This might be unrelated to Solr. The index being synced or not depends first and foremost on how indexing is triggered after some changes have been detected. If you manually change the state of a record, how is this reflected on the Solr side ? What is the logic triggering a Solr update request ?

Comment: A record's state can change to one of 10 fixed strings, and can go from one state to any other. Typically, a user clicks a button that updates a record's state, and then several days later runs the Solr query above and find the record they changed is still marked with its old state in the query results, but on the record's show page it will have the correct state.

The Solr update triggers are handled by the Sunspot gem, and AFAIK it should update every time an AR update is called. I thought there might be a bug with Sunspot but haven't found anyone else with this same issue using Sunspot.